# Understanding Magic Values

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I am trying to wrap my head around magic values in solidity code, but cant seem to find any resources on this.

Here is an example of a contract I am looking at:

```
/// @dev Magic value to be returned upon successful reception of an NFT
bytes4 constant ERC721_RECEIVED_NEW = 0x150b7a02;
bytes4 constant ERC721_RECEIVED_OLD = 0xf0b9e5ba;
bytes32 constant ERC998_MAGIC_VALUE = 0xcd740db5;
```

The full contract can be found here:https://etherscan.io/address/0xaaf401585b72c678afc09036510d3ef759bdaf7e#code
Would appreciate it if some could provide an explanation or point me to resources .

Comment: Where did you get the term "magic value"? What are you referring to?

Comment: updating my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These come from [ERC165](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-165.md), which gives contracts a way to query each other about what interfaces they support. The return value is the XOR of the [function selectors](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/abi-spec.html#function-selector) of the supported functions. In this case, here are the values:

```
bytes4 constant ERC721_RECEIVED_NEW = 0x150b7a02;
bytes4 constant ERC721_RECEIVED_OLD = 0xf0b9e5ba;
bytes32 constant ERC998_MAGIC_VALUE = 0xcd740db5;
```

and here is how they're derived:

```
web3.sha3('onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)').substring(0, 10) === "0x150b7a02"
web3.sha3('onERC721Received(address,uint256,bytes)').substring(0, 10) === "0xf0b9e5ba"
```

The last one is a little tougher. From  https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-998.md:

> `0xcd740db5` is equal to:
>
> ```
> this.rootOwnerOf.selector ^ this.rootOwnerOfChild.selector ^ 
> this.tokenOwnerOf.selector ^ this.ownerOfChild.selector;
> ```